# Android with Django: How to keep user logged in

Tags: android, django, authentication, facebook-login, django-authentication

I want to know what the method used by popular apps are.

Here are the approaches I have considered:

- When user logs in, save username & password in shared preferences and re-use it every time
  (**I think this will suck**)
- Login on the client(app) side with
  Facebook SDK, pass the authentication token to the app and use that
  to create a user. Pass a token to the app, store this token on the
  phone and use it in future communications. *I think it would make
  sense to re-create this token periodically, but how to do so without
  asking the user to login again?*
- Create a login view. *this will mean passing username and password to the API* And then go with the user token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you should store user credentials in preferences.

The most common approach is to send credentials to server and then as a response get a session key. Then include the session key as a header to any request (and validate it in every request).

If the session key would become invalid (e. g. expired) then the server should return a proper response, and the client should initialize authentication functionality.

Egzample

First run

1. Show login `Activity`
2. Send credentials to server
3. Get a `session_key` as a response (normally its a hash)
4. Store the `session_key` hash
5. User is authenticated, exit the login `Activity`

Any request to the server.

1. Add a header with `session_key` to your request (e. g. as a header)
2. Send the request
3. If the response is Ok Stop, else (e. g. response with message "not authorized" or status code 401) run `First run`

Comment: Regarding the client initializing authentication functionality, in web apps, I think it would be okay to redirect the user to the login screen, but this would not really be acceptable in apps.

So how would I go about reinitializing without asking the user to enter details again?

Comment: Why do you think that this would be not acceptable ? It makes a lot of sense if it is handled properly through the back-end (e. g. session keys have not to short expiration time)

Comment: The thing is, I use the facebook or gmail apps once a day and I've never had to log in repeatedly. What strategy are they following?

Comment: I would assume they use the same pattern as mentioned in my response - they use a session key. I have edited the post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

First run

- Show login Activity
- Send credentials to server
- Get a session_key
- User is authenticated, exit the login Activity
- you get the access tokens and login details to stored in Shared Preferences

For other request.

- Add a header with session_key to your request (e. g. as a header)
- Send the request